# jQuery and IE8 compatibility view

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer-8

While doing a front-end javacript performance test on a site I'm developing, I'm finding on IE8 standards mode everything runs ridiculously slow. But if I flip compatibility view on, it runs very well - the animations are much smoother.

Unfortunately I cannot upload a link to show, but one of the plugins I'm using is a magnifier:
http://www.huydinh.co.uk/demo/magnifier/

Toggle between compatibility mode, and move cursor around.

I also tried adding the EmulateIE7 meta tag, but it made no difference.
Has anyone encountered this before? Is there a way to fix it?

Please help!
Thanks.

Comment: i have exactly the same problem on a older page i have to work on. Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1):

Preferably you could get the site to work with reasonable perf in IE8 Standards mode. Have you tried forcing compatibility mode as documented here?

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/introducing-ieemulateie7)

One way (as noted in the article above) is to include the following `<meta>` tag right after the `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem before and fixed it by making adding a correct doctype and fixing all my page errors in the html validator: validator.w3.org  May not be what you're looking for but it's good practice anyways.

Comment: Thanks wajiw, but my page has always been valid to XHTML 1.0 transitional doctype, so don't think that's the cause of it..